# Node js , replacing occurrences in a nested data structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Basically I want to replace # occurrences in a string from an object. As you can see it replace occurences in templateName , description , comments and Name but I can't replace sections header and sections questions , how will I improve my loop to apply replaceOccurrences in sections.header and sections questions array of objects? . sections headers are array of objects I also want to include that. Any idea? thank you.

## Code

```
const replaceOccurrences = (originalString) => (typeof originalString === 'string' ? originalString.replace(/#/g, '&num;') : originalString);

const generateTemplate = async (data) => {

  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(data)) { data[k] = replaceOccurrences(v); }

  return template(data);
};
```

## Data

```
data :  {
  Name: 'Rajesh',
  sections: [
    {
      questions: [Array]
    }
  ],
  templateName: 'TEMPLAT#E',
  description: 'Tes#t',
  comments: "adasdada'dfgdfgdfg 'gfddf#gdfgdf #num;## ##fsdfds gdfgdfgfd##"
}
```

Comment: You need to write a recursive descent parser https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: can you provide example @slebetman based on my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James's answer will work if your obj is serializable, otherwise you'll need a recursive function

```js
const removePoundSign = cur => {
  if (typeof cur === 'string') {
    return cur.replace(/#/g, '&num;');
  }

  if (cur == null || typeof cur !== 'object') return cur;

  if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
    return cur.map(el => removePoundSign(el));
  }

  const newObj = {};
  for (const key in cur) {
    newObj[key] = removePoundSign(cur[key]);
  }
  return newObj;
};
```

also, theres no need for the function to be async in your code!

Comment: how do I make use of that removePoundSign inside my generateTemplate ?

Comment: and why is there no need to be async ?

Comment: @ShaneRajesh Because your function does not work with Promises

Comment: @ShaneRajesh you dont, you'd just pass data to this function and it outputs the object without pound signs. Your generateTemplate function is trying to do the same thing as my snippet, but you forget to handle arrays and other types.

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify the object, make your replacements, then return it to object form:

```js
let a = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/#/g, '&num;');
let b = JSON.parse(a);

Name: "Rajesh"
comments: "adasdada'dfgdfgdfg 'gfddf&num;gdfgdf &num;num;&num;&num; &num;&num;fsdfds gdfgdfgfd&num;&num;"
description: "Tes&num;t"
sections: Array(1)
0: {header: "Testing sec&num;tion", questions: Array(1)}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
templateName: "TECHNICAL TEMPLAT&num;E"
```